# Targeting CSS with JavaScript getElementById

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid

Simple question really, I'm using the getElementById to target my div `standby` and change its styling. Now, I can't for the love of anything find out how to target what is written in my CSS as `#standby img`, that is, the `img` tag within `standby`. How would I target this and change its styling with JavaScript?

Comment: how do you know it's a simple question ;-)

Comment: document.querySelector('#standby img') is fine? ;-) http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: mariozski That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plain javascript in all browsers, it would be this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementById("standby").getElementsByTagName("img");
```

In more advanced browsers, you could use this:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#standby img");
```

Each of these returns a nodeList (which is like an array of DOM elements) that you can then iterate over.

---

You could then iterate the results of either of these like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].style.width = "300px";
}
```

---

If you know there is one and only one image in that div, then you could just do this rather than iterating over more than one:

```
document.getElementById("standby").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.width = "300px";
```

Comment: I ended up using document.querySelector instead but this also helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use document.querySelector for a pure javascript solution:

```
document.querySelector("#erg img");
```

You can then change its style like you would with an element retrieved with getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jQuery. `$('#standby img')`. Worth looking into.

Comment: This is NOT a jQuery question.

Comment: If I were the poster, I would want to know that this kind of problem has a very popular framework that addresses it.

Comment: The convention here on StackOverflow is that you don't just blindly supply a jQuery answer to a question that has no mention or tag related to jQuery.

Comment: @ktm5124 if I were the poster, I'd also be happy to know that I can do it without jQuery and it's just as simple.

Answer (score 0):

So you've already got the `standby` element using `getElementById()`.

To get the `img` elements within it, you need to use `getElementsByTagName()`

```
var standby = document.getElementById('standby');
var standbyImgs = standby.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

I guess you already have the first line, so you just need the second. Or combine them into one.

Important to note that `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of elements, not a single element like `getElementById()`. Because obviously, there could be more than one `img` there, whereas there should only ever be one element with a given ID.